# How do I change the border of the ComboBoxEditor?

Tags: java, swing

I have a combobox on my dialog.

How do I change the color of the border on it´s editor-area?

The ComboBox is set to not editable (means, while running the project, I can only pick a content of it´s existing list, but not writing own content) and I don´t want to change it.

If I try to use

```
UIManager.put("ComboBox.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(dark_sand));
```

It adds only an extra border around the whole ComboBox.
But I just want to change the existing two-color-border of the editing-area.

This shows the actual look of my Dialog.
[image: Dialog-Preview 1]

```
UIManager.put("Button.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(dark_sand));
```

will set the border of the Combobox-Button too.
This is why I want to change only the existing border at the ComboBoxEditor.

This is how I want it look like (edited with Gimp)
[image: Dialog-Preview 2]

Which UIManager property or method-call changes the border of this part of the ComboBox

Comment: *Wich UIManager property or method-call changes the border of this part of the ComboBox* - I already told you there is no property. Not all Swing components have properties that can be changed by the UIManager. A JComboBox is a compound components that contains a JButton and JTextfield. The UI is handled by the LAF. Maybe you can create a custom UI. Use the `getUI()` method of the combo box to get the UI that is currently used and then try to customize the UI.

Comment: if the textfild-part of the Jcombobox is a JTextField, why i cannot set it´s border with TextField.border? someone found a methode to delete the bordr of both parts. so it must be able to write a method, that changes only the border of the textfield.

Comment: *why i cannot set it´s border with TextField.border?* - As I said above the UI will control the LAF and may very well manage the Border itself so that the individual text field and button look like a single component. Look at the UI code if you want to know the details. In any case, I would suggest you should not be attempting to change the border via the UIManager. Instead you could try changing the border of the instance of the text field that is used by the combo box. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: can you show mo how to find this instance to set it´s border?

Answer (score 0):

> can you show me how to find this instance to set it´s border?

Start by reading the API for `JComboBox`.

You will find a method to get the `ComboBoxEditor` for the combo box.

When you get the `ComboBoxEditor` you then read its API to find the method used to get the actual component used for the editor, which by default is a `JTextField`.

Then you set the `Border` of the text field.